# Why do these radio buttons not let you switch the checked option once you've selected one?

Tags: html, forms, input, radio-button

[Link to form](http://theblessedbirth.co.uk/#volunteer-form)

The form can be found at the link above.

Up until this morning the radio buttons and the form had been working as expected, however now users can't change their answer once they've picked from one of the two radio buttons even though they use the same input name. Using `$("#volunteer-form input:radio[name='gender']:checked").val()` I've found that the value is being correctly set and that the two buttons are still linked by a common name. Also, it appears possible to switch between the two using a bit of jQuery, like so:

`$("#volunteer-form input[name=gender][value=male]").prop('checked', true);`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

its because of your javascript block here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.inline').fancybox({
            'maxWidth': 600
        });
        $('.form').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

when you are clicking on the radio button inside the form your preventDefault is stopping the change of radiobutton state ... or maybe you already knew that.

What is the intended purpose of including the preventDefault where you have it?

Comment: Wow, nice spot. That's something I was using to prevent the page from jumping to the top due to the href="#" on the submit buttons but I've now removed the hash and am using href="javascript:void(0)" instead. If anyone could vote this answer up since I can't that'd be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you're welcome! Just come back when you've earned enough points to vote up! ;-)